# Casperjs Google Login Not working

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I having been working on some code to access my google finance portfolio, but the problem is I need to sign in with my google account. So i have made this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=EN', function() {
  this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
      this.echo(this.getTitle());
      document.querySelector('input#Email').value = username;
      document.querySelector('#next').click();
      document.querySelector('input#Passwd').value = password;
      document.querySelector('#signIn').click();
  }, 'GOOGLE EMAIL', 'PASSWORD');
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML()); // => 'The text included in the <h1 id=foobar>'

    casper.thenOpen('https://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view&pid=1&ei=pBrbVoDhM4iFjAGB-bKIAg', function() {
        this.echo(this.getHTML());
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });

});

casper.run();
```

Which does not log me in!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages of any kind?  If so, please show us.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. My code is not working, in that I am not logged in after the process.

Comment: Make screenshots along the way to see where it goes wrong. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: `this` inside of `casper.evaluate` refers to `window` and not `casper`. `casper.evaluate` is sandboxed, so you cannot use variables defined outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my original code I was selecting the wrong input boxes from the google page, instead it should look like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start("https://accounts.google.com/Login?hl=EN", function() {
  console.log("page loaded...");
  //console.log(this.getHTML());
  //document.querySelector('#Email').value = "kpfromer@gmail.com";
  //document.querySelector('#next').click();

  this.fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', {
    'input[name="Email"]': 'EMAIL',
  }); //Fills the email box with email
  this.click("#next"); //Fills the email box with email


  this.wait(500, function() { //Wait for next page to load
    console.log("Inside WAIT...");

    this.waitForSelector("#Passwd", //Wait for password box
      function success() {
        console.log("SUCCESS...");
        this.fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', {
          'input[name="Passwd"]': 'PASSWORD',
        }); //Fill password box with PASSWORD
        this.click("#signIn"); //Click sign in button
        this.wait(500, function() {}); //Wait for it fully sigin
      },
      function fail() {
        console.log("FAIL...");
      }

    );

  });
});
casper.run();
```

The reason why there are waits is that it takes a little bit for the page to fully load, and swap to other pages.

Comment: Two solutions for the new UI are available in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550584 - forcing it back to the old way or using keyboard character typing.